# Keyboard is open in tablet mode automatically in Windows 10

Tags: windows-store-apps, window, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I writing code for Windows 8.1 and that app will be run in Windows 10 but issue is that whenever file picker opens a dialog box soft keyboard is open in tablet mode automatically when user using tablet mode.

How I can restrict keyboard or Refocus so that keyboard will not open?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot restrict this.

There is no way to prevent this in the default file dialogs, because they are provided by the system itself and you have very little control over their behavior and UI.

Moreover, the keyboard showing automatically in tablet mode is the default system behavior, which the user expects.